# Python parentheses seem to be changing equality evaluation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm comparing two strings and was banging my head against the wall for an hour trying to figure out why they weren't equal. Turns out I needed parentheses to clarify what was being evaluated.
Could someone explain what's happening here?

This code:

```
print("Line 1 equal=%s" % actual_line1 == expected_line1)
```

Evaluates to:

```
False
```

This code:

```
print("Line 1 equal=%s" % (actual_line1 == expected_line1))
```

Evaluates to:

```
Line 1 equal=True
```

Comment: `%` is `%`. The special behaviour for strings happens *when it comes time to evaluate that*, and *not* when the line is being compiled to bytecode. It is the same thing as how `1 % 2 == 3` gives `False`, but `1 % (2 == 3)` raises a `ZeroDivisionError`.

Comment: Please use modern tools to format the output: for example, `print(f"Line 1 equal={actual_line1 == expected_line1}")`. `%`-style formatting has numerous gotchas.

Comment: But please also consider what you are asking *in general*. Yes, parentheses commonly change the result of an expression, because they specify the *order of evaluation*. That is, after all, *what they are for*.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is equivalent to

```py
print(("Line 1 equal=%s" % actual_line1) == expected_line1)
```

because of operator precedence. According to a [relevant python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), `%` has higher precedence than `==` (look at the table therein as well as footnote 6).

Nowadays it is recommended to use an f-string, which is more readable:

```py
print(f"Line 1 equal={actual_line1 == expected_line1}")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because

```py
print("Line 1 equal=%s" % actual_line1 == expected_line1)
```

is the same as

```py
 print(("Line 1 equal=%s" % actual_line1) == expected_line1)
```

Instead of

```py
print("Line 1 equal=%s" % (actual_line1 == expected_line1))
```

which is what you wanted.
[More info](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)